# Is it possible to monitor the event listeners in an HTML element to know when one of them is removed?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, removeeventlistener

I have a problem in a page with an event not being fired under certain circumstances. It's not my code and I'm trying to debug minified and obscured JavaScript code and I'm going crazy.

When replying to a comment in our website, if the text of the reply is empty this event (an analytics event to register that the user clicked the reply button) is fired. If there's text, the event isn't fired.

The element is a `<span>` tag, but the event listener is actually attached to the `<body>` tag. My current theory is that some code that's being executed when there's actually text in the reply is removing that event listener and therefore it's not being fired.

So, is there a way to monitor the event listeners in `<body>` to know when (and where in the code) is this event listener being removed?

**Update**
We found the problem. The third-party library we use for the comments is removing the parent element of the button and that's making impossible for the event to propagate to body.

Comment: Maybe [visual event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) helps you.

Answer (score 2):

If you can run script code before the event handler is removed, you can replace `removeEventListener` on `document.body` with your own function:

```js
const original = document.body.removeEventListener;
document.body.removeEventListener = function(...args) {
  console.log("Removed");
  return original.apply(this, args);
};

function handler() {
  console.log("Clicked");
}
document.body.addEventListener("click", handler);
document.body.removeEventListener("click", handler);
```

(To cover your bases you might also convert `onclick` (or whatever is being used) to an accessor so you can capture it if code does `document.body.onclick = null;`)

There are other ways a handler can be added and removed, but hopefully whatever library you're using uses the standard.

---

Side note: To confirm your theory about the handler being removed, you can inspect the handlers on an element in Chrome's devtools: Right-click on the page and choose "Inspect element", navigate up to `body`, and look on the Event Listeners tab.

Comment: And you can `throw new Error()` inside the handler to get a stack trace, which might help pinpoint the location of the code that removes the listener, if helpful

Comment: Thanks, @T.J.Crowder, this has been very useful. I've found that indeed an event listener is being removed, but not the one I'm concerned about. Gotta keep looking, but thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use also the google developers tools that you can open with a button on the top right corner on the window. In the source section you can see al the event listener